# HTML Units Aren't Displaying

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This JSFiddle is the behavior I want: https://jsfiddle.net/nstruth/t0dopzav/1/

The HTML is displaying when I select Volvo, but the JavaScript isn't running. I looked at other innerHTML JavaScript questions, but I'm confused. As you can see in this JSFiddle the units aren't populating but I can enter numbers in the input fields.

https://jsfiddle.net/nstruth/ph3czotf/4/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="STYLE.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script> // In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cars2").select2();
});
</script>

<style>..
select {
width: 150px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV"><p>Hello</p></div>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars2" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="0">Pick something</option>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<script>
function myFunction(event){
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 //here you are picking the selected option item
 var y = $('#cars2 :selected').val();
 switch (y) {
  case '1':
    x.innerHTML = `<p>From:</p>
  <select style="float:left" id="MetricAndImperialLength1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="Run1()" onchange="Run1()">
    </select>



  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="Input1" type="number" oninput="Run1()" onchange="Run1()">

  <p>To:</p>

  <select style="float:left" id="MetricAndImperialLength2" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="Run2()" onchange="Run2()">   
  </select>

  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="Input2" type="number" oninput="Run2()" onchange="Run2()" />`;

$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
    break;
  case '2':
    x.innerHTML = "<p>Roy!</p>";
  }
}
</script>
<script src="mathandstuff.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Distance Math

var units = [
  ['Inches', 0.025400000000000],
  ['Feet', 0.30480000000000000],
  ['Furlongs', 201.168],
  ['Meters', 1.00]
];
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.newClass1');

for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = units[i][1];
    option.textContent = units[i][0];
    selectors[j].add(option);
  }
}

    function Run1() {
      var SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperialLength1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperialLength2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue.toFixed(12);
       
    }

    function Run2() {
      var SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperialLength2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperialLength1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue.toFixed(12);
    }
```

Please help a noob out.

Thanks

Comment: Avoid adding DOM elements dynamically like this, it makes the application more confusing. Put everything in the HTML, then hide and show elements as needed.

Comment: It doesn't take up space if you use `display: none;`

Comment: Can u please help me make a JavaScript function that displays the div but keeps other divs hidden based on  a switch case statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. JavaScript, and jQuery, run upon the loading of the document and are bound to other events. When you add items dynamically, the original bindings may not apply. It's not entirely clear what you want to have happen, yet I suspect that you may need to assign more callbacks after new items are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with display:none and jQuery. Here is my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nstruth/482sgxcu/9/

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="STYLE.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script> // In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cars2').select2();
$('#cars2').select2('open');
});
</script>

<style>..
select {
width: 150px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV"><p>Hello</p></div>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars2">
<option value="red">Pick something</option>
  <option value="yellow">Volvo</option>
  <option value="blue">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#cars2').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="yellow" style="display:none">
<p>From:</p>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<select style="float:left;" id="MetricAndImperialLength1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1 colors" oninput="Run1()" onchange="Run1()">
    </select>



  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000" id="Input1" type="number" oninput="Run1()" onchange="Run1()">

  <p>To:</p>

&nbsp;&nbsp;  <select style="float:left" id="MetricAndImperialLength2" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="Run2()" onchange="Run2()">   
  </select>

  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000" id="Input2" type="number" oninput="Run2()" onchange="Run2()" /></div>
<script src="mathandstuff.js"></script>
<script>
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing and matching functions from standard JavaScript (like `getElementById`) with functions from JQuery.  It's generally going to be better to stick to one framework as much as possible.  Otherwise you end up with disorganized code.  As @Barmar suggests you should separate your HTML and code as much as possible (again, because it's disorganized and hard to read).

You might try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cars2').on('change', function(event) {
    $('#myDIV').html($(`.placeholders div:nth-child(${$(this).val()})`).html());
  })
  $('select.run1').on('change', Run1)
  $('input.run1').on('input', Run1)
  $('input.run1').on('change', Run1)
  $('select.run2').on('change', Run2)
  $('input.run2').on('input', Run2)
  $('input.run2').on('change', Run2)
});

function Run1() {
 // omitted for clarity
}

function Run2() {
 // omitted for clarity
}
```

```css
.js-example-basic-single {
  float: left
 }
 
.runInput {
   height:50%;
   font-size:15pt;
   width:1000px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDIV"><p>Hello</p></div>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select id="cars2">
<option value="0">Pick something</option>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>

<div class="placeholders" style="display:none">
  <div>
    <p>From:</p>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1 run1">
    </select>
    <input class="runInput run1" type="number">
    <p>To:</p>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1 run2">   
    </select>
    <input class="runInput run2" type="number"/>
  </div>
  <div><p>Roy!</p></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8t7qn6Lc/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var units = {
    Inches: 0.0254,
    Feet: 0.3048,
    Furlongs: 201.168,
    Meters: 1
  };
  var selectors = $('.newClass1');

  function Run1() {
    var self = parseFloat($("#Input1").val());
    var SpecialValue = self * units[$("#MetricAndImperialLength1").val()] / units[$("#MetricAndImperialLength2").val()];
    $("#Input1").val(self.toFixed(12));
    $("#Input2").val(SpecialValue.toFixed(12));
  }

  function Run2() {
    var self = parseFloat($("#Input2").val());
    var SpecialValue = self * units[$("#MetricAndImperialLength2").val()] / units[$("#MetricAndImperialLength1").val()];
    $("#Input2").val(self.toFixed(12));
    $("#Input1").val(SpecialValue.toFixed(12));
  }

  function myFunction(event) {
    var x = $("#myDIV");
    x.html("");
    var y = $('#cars2').val();
    console.log(y);
    switch (y) {
      case '1':
        $("<p>").html("From:").appendTo(x);
        x.append($("#temp1").html());
        $("select:last", x).attr("id", "MetricAndImperialLength1");
        $("input:last", x).attr("id", "Input1").val("1.000000000000");
        $("select:last, input:last", x).on("input change", Run1);
        $("<p>").html("To:").appendTo(x);
        x.append($("#temp1").html());
        $("select:last", x).attr("id", "MetricAndImperialLength2");
        $("input:last", x).attr("id", "Input2").val("0.025400000000");
        $("select:last option:last", x).prop("selected", true);
        $("select:last, input:last", x).on("input change", Run2);
    }
  }

  $("#cars2").change(myFunction).Select2();
});
```

This has been switched over to jQuery for all parts. When "Volvo" is selected, new content is added and bound to `Run1` and `Run2` respectively.

Switching to an Object can help will your calculations. Now you can use the Value of each drop down as the Index for the Object when performing calculations.

Input type, even as Number, will always return a String. To ensure proper calculations, it is best to cast it as the proper Float.

Comment: The calculations are accurate enough without parseFloat. With your fiddle, you can only input one number, and the fields get frozen afterwards.